# Hola, debo hacer una suma acumulativa cada que invoco un metodo y siempre que invoque ese metodo debo guardar la suma anterior

Tags: python

necesito hacer una suma acumulativa dentro de una clase, cada que invoco un método y siempre que invoque ese método debo guardar la suma anterior. El ejemplo esta en la función cargar, así es como me imagino el iterador, pero ahora debo guardar ese iterador para utilizarlo cada que llame de nuevo al metodo.

```
class Electrolinera(ma):
    
    def __init__(self, ID, ubicacion, energia_otorgada, cargas_totales):
        super().__init__(self)
        
        self.ID=ID
        self.ubicacion=ubicacion
        self.energia_otorgada=energia_otorgada
        self.cargas_totales=cargas_totales#Colocamos la palabra reservada self para poder cambiar las intancias de los atributos
        



    def informar(self):
        self.ubicacion=input("Ingrese la ubicacion")
        self.energia_otorgada=7500
        self.cargas_totales= 2
        if self.energia_otorgada==7500:
            ct=self.energia_otorgada*self.cargas_totales

        
        return f"La ubicacion de la electrolinera es {self.ubicacion} y la energía otorgada {self.energia_otorgada}W/h y las cargas totales que ha realizado durante una semana {ct}W/h."
        
        
    def cargar(self):#Creamos una funcion donde sea posible agregar las cargas a la máquina
        
        i=0

        while True:
            i=+1
            self.cargas_totales+=i#Incrementamos la carga totales con esta asignación
            sa=(self.cargas_totales+self.energia_otorgada)#Sumamos las cargas declarando otra variable
            #sa=False
            return f"La suma de energías es: {sa}"#Imprimimos la suma de las cargas dentro de la funcion
            break  
        
c=Electrolinera(202020, 1, 2, 3 )
print(c.informar())
print(c.cargar())

b=ma(False)
print(b.apagar())
print(b.encender())
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu problema? ¿Cuál es el error?. ¿Solo tienes que guardar la suma anterior o todas las sumas anteriores?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo guardo?

Comment: De la misma forma en la que guardas el ID, la ubicación, la energía otorgada y las cargas totales.

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo?

Comment: No necesitas un ejemplo. En tu código ya estas haciendo algo similar con las `cargas_totales`.

Answer (score 0):

Este es el esqueleto de una clase con "acumulador".

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor = None
        self.totalizador = 0

    def metodo_con_acumulador(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.totalizador += valor
```

Lo esencial es que el método recibe un valor a acumular. La cuenta se lleva en el atributo `totalizador`. Cada vez que se recibe un valor, se agrega al total.

**Demo**

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor = None
        self.totalizador = 0
                
    def metodo_con_acumulador(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.totalizador += valor
        
x = Clase()
x.metodo_con_acumulador(1)
x.metodo_con_acumulador(2)
x.metodo_con_acumulador(3)
print(f"El total es {x.totalizador}")
print(f"El último valor ingresado es {x.valor}")
```

produce:

```
El total es 6
El último valor ingresado es 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Nota:

Con esta solución puedes obtener el total acumulado y el último valor ingresado. Si quieres almacenar más valores que sólo el último recibido, puedes usar una lista:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.valor = []
        self.totalizador = 0

    def metodo_con_acumulador(self, valor):
        self.valor.append(valor)
        self.totalizador += valor
```